# How to get Django to work with MySQL in XAMPP?

Tags: python, mysql, django, sockets, xampp

I installed XAMPP on my Mac (Snow Leopard) and installed Django. How do I tell Django to use this and when I fire up `python manage.py runserver` I get this error:

```
...
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

How do I tell Django to use this instead?

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put that in the [`HOST`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#host) entry for the database in the settings.

Comment: After all the complicated "fixes", this is the one that worked! Thanks :)

Comment: how can you do this in windows?

Comment: @2one2: MySQL on Windows does not use a socket file. Use TCP/IP instead.

Comment: I am quite new. I am just wondering that, should I need to install anything for connecting django and xampp mysql database or not?

Comment: this is the answer thanks a lot. I was searching for 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

simple solution is that just install Django Stack for Xampp. Not need to configure any thing every thing is configured already

https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_Django_Stack