# Installation mysql for django with xampp on linux

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, xampp

**After trying to start my django with:**

[image]

**I obtain the following result :**
[image]

**I'm using xampp to handle my mysql database and it works:**

[image]

**So in order to solve the problem, i follow this tutorial and execute this command:**

[image]

**But the output is this following error that i'm trying to solve for 3 days "Subprocess returned an error code" :**

[image]

**I already tried all the solution i found on the web but nothing seems to work, if somebody can try to help me it would be awesome**

*Thanks for your time*

Comment: You can try this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051043/how-to-get-django-to-work-with-mysql-in-xampp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i was forced to create a new virtual machine and there is no problem anymore...